# Rails, Helicon Zoo, & IIS Authentication redirect loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iis, helicontech

I've setup a rails site on a server running Windows Server 2008 + IIS 7.0. When navigating to the site the browser gets caught in a redirect loop causes by this code

```
def authorize 
  if not signed_in? 
    previous_url = request.fullpath 
    redirect_to signin_path, :notice => "Please sign in to access this page" 
  end
end
```

I've started it from the console (`rails s -e production`) and had no issues. I've also set it up on my development machine (Windows 7 + IIS 7.5) and not had issues. At this point I'm not sure where to start poking around.

Comment: If the signin_path isn't excluded from your authorize filter, it too will try to redirect.

Comment: it is. The site runs fine everywhere except on the remote server's IIS

Answer (score 0):

Does your server give you an error log? That may be a good place to start. (For example on linux if I issue this command in terminal: `rails server -e dev2 --port 3010` it will spit out all errors and a lot of other things, like sql queries, to the terminal window).

Comment: There are no errors, just redirects. Running rails from the console works fine; the problems arise when I host it with IIS.